# How can I get Gradle to comply with the properties standard?

Tags: gradle, properties

I am converting a massive project to Gradle. I do not have permission to change any of the property names since Maven has to continue working until I finish in a few months. Naturally they are all of the form "this.that.the.other.thing" and gradle fails to load them accordingly:

```
* Where:
Script '/dev/proj/default.properties' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find property 'database' on root project
```

What it's trying to load is a property called "`database.connection.properties`" which is a path to the location of a file that contains additional properties. I think it's dropping dead on the period, but I'm stuck with the property names as they are.

How can I get Gradle to comply with the properties standard?

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dotted-properties-in-gradle/6845/2 Potentially worth looking at.

Comment: No access to ConfigSlurper. Do I need to import it or something?

Comment: It's their project and they can do what ever they want with it but I see them making many of the same mistakes made in previous build systems. They keep saying it's flexible, but it sure doesn't seem like it. I can't even call my properties what I want. That's not what I call flexible.

Comment: I'm thinking it's available @ `groovy.util.ConfigSlurper`

Comment: Huh? I don't understand. New to both Groovy and Gradle. Tried 
@groovy.util.ConfigSlurper - didn't work. Tried import groovy.util.ConfigSlurper, didn't work. Tho me a bone here.

Comment: I haven't done much with groovy/gradle myself but I'm thinking you can just `import groovy.util.ConfigSlurper` as you would in Java.

Comment: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'default_profile_dmmqiztond012huu6njr8dkq1' String index out of range: 22

Nice. :-|  I think what I'm seeing here is that ConfigSlurper can't handle a name longer than 22 characters.